# Building a previous version of Chromium browser

Tags: build, chromium

I'm trying to build a previous version of the Chromium browser that still had NPAPI support. I've gotten the code and I'm able to build the latest version of Chromium on my mac by using the stand build commands

```
gclient sync
ninja -C out/Debug chrome
```

everything works great I can run chrome after that. So I tried

```
git checkout tags/41.0.2272.96 -b npapi
ninja -C out/Debug chrome
```

but I end up getting

```
'../../chrome/app/chrome_exe_main_mac.c', needed by 'obj/chrome/app/helper_app.chrome_exe_main_mac.o', missing and no known rule to make it`
```

Is there a standard way to rebuild a previous version of chromium? everything I find is about getting the latest and building it but nothing about going back to a previous version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions you want are at [the top of this page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches).

What you are missing in your current steps is the `gclient sync`, which will pull the correct version of all the dependencies, and also regenerate the build files based on the current sources. (The error in your question is almost certainly due to the latter.)

Comment: I had to add the `--with_branch_heads` but that seemed to get me working on my mac.